# In C# WPF projects what determines the default size of UI elements in the XAML?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have two C# WPF solutions. For some reason on solution #1, the default values for UI elements do not match the default values for solution #2.

I am trying to find where the default values for this solution are stored.

Here is an example.

I generate a new button using the XAML code:

```
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

Solution 1:
I create a new button.
The button's default height is 22 pixels. The button's default font is "Segoe UI" and the default font size is 12px.

Solution 2:
I create a new button.
The button's default height is 28 pixels. The button's default font is "Calibri" and the default font size is 18px.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3vYf.png is a screenshot showing the properties that I am seeing being displayed. Where can I find what is setting these default values per solution since it does not appear to be stored directly in the XAML?

Edit: You were correct! The default font style and size were being defined in the Window XAML code.

```
<Window x:Class="test.test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        FontFamily="Calibri"
        FontSize="16"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the container control that the buttons are enclosed in. The Button's implicit style can be set in many ways, so the button can pickup these default values from many places.

For example, if the button is inside a 3rd-party custom control, then the default font may be set to Calibri, rather than the global default of Segoe